# плавное выезжание блока с помощью CSS или JS

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Задача следующая: поставить затемнение на экран при нажатии на кнопку и обратно убирать затемнение при повторном нажатии.

Реализация: сделал див на весь экран с черным цветом и опасити, дал ему margin-left: -20000px. На Js записал изменение этого марджина с -20000 до 0 и обратно. А как можно сделать плавное заезжание? Смотрелось бы интереснее

JS

```
document.querySelector('.menu-icon-wrapper').onclick = function(){
        var dark = document.querySelector('.dark')
        document.querySelector('.menu-icon').classList.toggle('menu-icon-active');
        dark.style.marginLeft = (dark.style.marginLeft == '0px')? '-10000000px': '0px'
    }
```

Css

```
.dark{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -10000000px;
```

}

Comment: Ого, я такой подход видел лет 10 назад... Сделайте лучше нормально, что бы блок добавлялся и удалялся из DOM. Анимацию можете сделать с помощью [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать всю логику стилей в стилях, а в js задавать классы-состояния.

```js
document.querySelector('#nav').onclick = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

body.dark:after {
  transform: translateX(10000px);
}
```

```html
<button id="nav">nav</button>
```

А анимацию делать через transform - она выносит в отдельный слой рендеринга (или как-то там) и работает быстрее и плавнее.

Comment: А почему бы не задвинуть див `transform: translateX(-10000px);`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, так будет лучше (чище)

Answer (score 1):

Появление

```js
var flag = true;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if (flag){
    sh.style.backgroundColor = '#000000f0';
  }
  else{
    sh.style.backgroundColor = '#00000000';
  }
  flag = !flag;
})
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
}

.shadow {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
<div class="container">
<div id="sh" class="shadow"></div>
<div class="content" style="height:100%">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/6c/f7/766cf770ea8dd3529bd8e0c41d6784be.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
</div>
```

Выезжание:

```js
var flag = true;
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if (flag){
    sh.style.left = '0';
  }
  else{
    sh.style.left = '-120%';
  }
  flag = !flag;
})
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
}

.shadow {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: #000000f0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-120%;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
<div class="container">
<div id="sh" class="shadow"></div>
<div class="content" style="height:100%">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/6c/f7/766cf770ea8dd3529bd8e0c41d6784be.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
</div>
```